# Chaining rxjs 6 observables with nested array

Tags: rxjs, observable

I have to do 3 dependent request to an API.

1. The first retreive an array of user id's.
2. The second have to iterate over the user id's array and for each retreive an array of project id's related to the user.
3. The third have to iterate over the project id's array and retreive data related to projects.

I want this kind of result:

```
[{'username': 'richard', projects: [{"id": 1, "name": "test"}]}, ...]
```

But i'm totally stuck with mergeMap, forkJoin etc..

The thing i have tried:

```
getUserTeamMembers(): Observable<any> {
return this.http.get(`${environment.serverUrl}/user/profil`).pipe(
  mergeMap((teamUsers: any) =>
    this.http.get(
      `api/user/${teamUsers.data._id}/team`
    )
  ),
  mergeMap((teamUsers: any) =>
    forkJoin(
      ...teamUsers.data.map((user: any) =>
        this.http.get(`api/user/${user.id}`)
      )
    )
  ),
  map((res: any) =>
    res
      .map((user: any) => {
        if (user.data) {
          return {
            firstname: user.data.local.firstname,
            lastname: user.data.local.lastname,
            email: user.data.local.email,
            projects: user.data.local.projects,
            language: user.data.local.lang
          };
        }
      })
      .filter((user: any) => user !== undefined)
  ),
  tap(t => console.log(t)),
  catchError(err => throwError(err))
);}
```

I try so many things, but i have no clue where to populate my array of projects which is currently only contains id's, not data related:

```
[{'username': 'richard', projects: ['id1', 'id2']}, ...]
```

Answer (score 1):

have made a similar example hope it clear the idea.

of course did't use http instead made it local using `of`

and stored the final result in an array called `results`

we have a source to get the list of all users, another source that given the user id it will return the list of this user's projects' ids `projectList`, and finally a source that give one project id will returns it's details(`projcectsDetails`)

```js
    let users = of([ 1, 2, 3 ])
    let projectsList = (userId) => of([ userId, userId*2 ]) 
    let projectsDetails = (projectId) => of({ id: projectId, details: `details about ${projectId}` })


    let results = [];

    users
    .pipe(
      tap(users => {
        users.forEach(userId => results.push({ userId, projects: [] }));

        return users
      }),
      switchMap(users => forkJoin(users.map(userId => projectsList(userId)))),
      switchMap(projectsArray => forkJoin(
          projectsArray.map(
            oneProjectArray => 
            forkJoin(oneProjectArray.map(projectId => projectsDetails(projectId)))
          )
        )
      ),
      tap(projectDetailsArray => {
        projectDetailsArray.forEach((projectsArray, index) =>{
          results[index]['projects'] = [ ...projectsArray ]
        })
      })
    )
    .subscribe(() => console.warn('final',results))
```

explanation

```
  1- initalize the result array from the given users
  [ 
   { userId: X, projcts: [] }, 
   { userId: Y, projcts: [] }, 
    ....
  ]

  2- for each give users we want the projects ids he/she has
  so the first switchMap will return (in order)
  [
   [ 1, 2, 3, ...] project ids for the first user,
   [ 8, 12, 63, ...] project ids for the second user,
   ...
  ]

  3- in the second switchMap we iterate over the previous array
  (which is an array that each item in it is an array of projects ids)

  so we needed two forkJoin the outer will iterate over each array of projects ids(the big outer 
  array previously mentioned)
  the inner one will iterate over each single project id and resolve it's observable value(which is the
  project details)

  4- finally in the tap process we have an array of array like the 2nd step but this time each
  array has the projects details and not the projects ids

  [
   { userId:1, projects: [ { id:1, details: 'details about 1' }, { id:2, details: 'details about 2' }]},
   { userId:2, projects: [ { id:2, details: 'details about 2' }, { id:4, details: 'details about 4' }]},
   { userId:3, projects: [ { id:3, details: 'details about 3' }, { id:6, details: 'details about 6' }]}
  ]
```

Comment: Excelent answer and nice explanation but I think the taps blow up the answer unnecessary. Just an opinion :)

Comment: thank you for your time, i have an error now, when i do the last 2 forkJoin, my db gets called correctly but all my requests were cancelled, so when i finally tap there is nothing in the result.

Comment: @amerej  sorry, my fault. switchMap will cancel previous requests or events, so try mergeMap instead of the second switchMap, if it works tell me to update the answer.

Comment: @LouayAlosh yep, it works with merge map but now, i don't find a way to get the result array created, if i return results in tap it returns the good result but as many times as he found results in the last mergeMap, if i don't return results it returns me an array of undefined :(

Comment: @amerej the question is does projectDetailsArray in the last tap return what you want in the order you need?

Comment: check the `tap` documentation https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/tap `tap` is not meant to return anything, my only use is to separate the steps no more.

Comment: @LouayAlosh "the question is does projectDetailsArray in the last tap return what you want in the order you need?" yes

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207993/discussion-between-amerej-and-louay-alosh).